# Not able to get currently focused element

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jquery autoresize plugin to resize my textarea

In the plugin i have something like this..

```
(function($){   
    $.fn.autoResize = function(options, idToBeShown) {

    updateSize = function() {
      //shows the content underneath the textbox with a slidedown effect    
    },

    resetSize = function(event) {
      //Slide up and hide the contents underneath the textarea  
    },


  textarea
    .unbind('.dynSiz')
    .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
    .bind('focus',updateSize)   //slide's down when focused
    .bind('focusout',changeSize)    //Slide up and hide the contents underneath the textarea
    .bind('change.dynSiz', updateSize);



  });
```

My problem is when i click the area underneath the textarea the textarea should not slideUp but instead 
when i click anywhere in the body it should slide up..

So i did this..

```
resetSize = function(event) {
//check the current focused element if it is the div area under text do do anything else slideup    
},
```

I'm not able to get the currently focused element

1) document.activeElement returns body

2) tried is(":focus");

3) is(":active")

Nothing works ... Note i have also added 'id' to the div element..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

updateSize()

```
//process
$('#divId').addClass('active');
```

resetSize()

```
if($('#divId').hasClass('active')){
    //process
    $('#divId').removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(":input").focus(function () {

    $(document).click(function(e) {
         //resetSize;
    });

});
```

Comment: Won't that bind a new click handler to the document each time the input is focused?

Comment: Sorry - so used to doing vanilla javascript - I updated the click handler so it adds a click method instead of replacing.